# leakage across diode and transistor

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, diodes

[image]

If the voltage at pount K1A2 is around 3V(less than 5v), the lower diode of BAV99W/DG/B2 is reverse biased , and also the transistor is T200 is in off condition , but will there be leakages across them ? what should I look for in the datasheets of the diode and transistor to find out the leakage in them for the above mentioned condition.

http://www.vishay.com/docs/85718/bav99.pdf

Comment: sry , I couldn't include the datasheet of the transistor since I don't have enough reputation.http://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PDTC114E_SER.pdf

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty sure you can look up the current through T201(left half) directly from the PUMD2 datasheet, so what's your question?

Comment: *but will there be leakages across them ?* Yes, **always**. There aren't any (solid-state) diodes which do no leak **at all**.

Comment: as usual, it might be relevant to know from which perspective, and to what purpose you're approaching this. I feel like I'm pointing to http://xyproblem.info the 10,000th time...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For the diode, look at datasheet page 2. The spec you want is 
"Reverse current":

VR = 70 V IR=2500 nA
VR = 70 V, Tj = 150 °C 50 μA
VR = 25 V, Tj = 150 °C 30 μA

These are guaranteed maximum values. However, these are for different voltages. Let's check a different datasheet.

http://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BAV99_SER.pdf

Fig.2 Page 5 will give you a typical (not maximum) reverse current for various temperatures. This will give you a very good idea of how the leakage current depends on conditions.

For the transistor...

http://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PDTC114E_SER.pdf

Table 8 page 7 : ICEO collector-emitter cut-off current

There is no curve, though.

Comment: Thank you , also can you please tell me the conditions for T201(PNP) to go into saturation. What will be the collector current then ?

Comment: I have a resistor in this circuit which is exceeding it's maximum wattage rating , how do I change it without changing the layout of the pcb ?

Comment: can you help me out